# Some problems with my LAN's shared resources through OpenVPN on Pfsense 2.4.4

Tags: firewall, openvpn, pfsense

I installed OpenVPN server on my pfSense machine, and the OpenVpn client on one of my notebooks. Everything seems to be working fine; I can successfully connect to pfsense machine (dashboard) from my notebook. However, I can't get access to my Windows 10 PC's shared folders unless I completely disable its firewall. Is there any way to get access to my shared folder on Windows 10 without disabling its firewall?

Comment: Is your windows 10 connection set as "Private" or "Public"? Public is meant to deny access from the network.
Also if disabling the firewall solves the issue you might be able to solve it by [adding an inbound port rule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-firewall/create-an-inbound-port-rule)
Depending on your issue I might add an answer or the other... Or maybe something else...

Comment: @Zip My windows 10 connection is set as "Private". Which rule should I add? For the record, I have no problem to access this windows 10 PC's shared folders from any other PCs on my LAN when I am not using OpenVPN.

Comment: You should add rules that allow the OpenVPN network to access your PCs port 445 (smb port). Perhaps you may need also port 139 which was for older versions.